# Connections problems while some activities - xChat, GAE - on Ubuntu

Tags: connection, ubuntu-11.04, xchat, google-app-engine

I have very annoying problem with a connection.
When I browse Internet using for example - firefox - there are no problems, but if I try to connect to any server - it just can't be done - I have connection time outs over and over again. Same thing happens when I try to deploy my application in Google App Engine. Weird thing is that sometimes - after 20-30 attemps it deploys properly. I'm pretty sure that the problem is somewhere in my netbook - not in wifi. It's because this problem occurs everywhere, and this problem doesn't occur on my other laptop with same OS and connected to same WIFI.
Both computers had Ubuntu reinstalled recently and their HDD's have been formated.
OS - Ubuntu 11.04
Netbook - Asus EEE PC 1000H
I haven't found anything on google that would help with this problem.
I would be thankful for any help.

edit: plus addintional - something that I forgot about - I can't add repository through terminal, but I get error: trying to get gpg key. Time out of course